# Is it OK to create a List of controls just to set some shared properties in a foreach instead of on mulitiple lines?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-3.5

I have code that looks something like this :

```
if (someCondition)
{
    control1.Enabled = true;
    control1.BackColor = Colors.CornSilk;
    control2.Enabled = true;
    control2.BackColor = Colors.CornSilk;
    control3.Enabled = true;
    control3.BackColor = Colors.CornSilk;
    ...
} 
else 
{
    control1.Enabled = false;
    control1.BackColor = default(Color);
    control2.Enabled = false;
    control2.BackColor = default(Color);
    control3.Enabled = false;
    control3.BackColor = default(Color);
    ...
}
```

Is there any downside in memory or performance for creating a list for these Controls, and using a loop instead?

```
var requiredControls = new List<Control>() { control1, control2, control3, .. };

if (someCondition)
{
    foreach(var c in requiredControls)
    {
        c.Enabled = true;
        c.BackColor = Colors.CornSilk;
    }
} 
else 
{
    foreach(var c in requiredControls)
    {
        c.Enabled = false;
        c.BackColor = default(Color);
    }
}
```

Or even

```
var requiredControls = new List<Control>() { control1, control2, control3, .. };

foreach(var c in requiredControls)
{
    c.Enabled = someCondition;
    c.BackColor = (someCondition ? Colors.CornSilk : default(Color);
}
```

Comment: If there is a downside in memory or performance, it is not big enough to even notice

Comment: I would expect any performance difference to be negligible.

Comment: Not too much difference between their performance but if you use last one that means you are a good programmer with code-design skills.

Comment: That code looks WinForm-ish.  I thought you were a WPF programmer?  Odd question though, because if you ran both examples, you clearly wouldn't have perceived a performance difference.

Comment: @LarsTech I've been working in WinForms the last couple years, and the project I'm working on now is not too well optimized and has memory issues as it is. I'm afraid I still don't know as many details on the inner workings of C# as I would like. (As a side note, I miss WPF!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about raw performance difference, then the first one is the best in terms of performance, **BUT**, as mentioned from all the comments and answers the difference will be negligible in this specific case.

The small overhead will be of creating the list and looping through it, consider that fact that in compiler optimization, there is a step that is done to many loops which is `loop unrolling`, which will reduce the loop steps and write the lines one by one instead of looping through all.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is perfectly fine, and any performance hit will be too small to even think about.

What you really need to worry about is readability.  What you've done is plenty readable, but there are other language features that you might be able to employ to make it even more readable.

The `params` keyword is one tool that you can use.  here's a demonstration.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo1 = new Foo() { Bar = 1 };
        var foo2 = new Foo() { Bar = 2 };
        AddOne(foo1, foo2);
    }

    public static void AddOne(params Foo[] foos)
    {
        foreach(var foo in foos)
        {
            foo.Bar++;
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Obligatory params reference](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords/2513/params#t=201607291923002663376)